# Creating procedure using courser in mysql

Tags: mysql, procedure

I want to create one procedure. It will fetch data from `client_master` table.

`client_master` table contains `member_id`, `mobileno`, `password` etc columns with `member_id` having more than 1 lakh (100 000) records.

I had created another table named  `client_master_test`.

Now I want to insert all data from `client_master` to `client_master_test`.

Before inserting I want to update `member_id`, `mobileno`, `password` columns data with `test@test`.

So, I want to use cursor which selects one `member_id`, updates those columns and inserts it to the next table.

Can anyone help me to create such procedure?

Comment: For anyone reading this not from India - `1 lakh = 100 000`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SELECT INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) syntax and update the values afterwards.

```
INSERT INTO client_master_test SELECT * FROM client_master;
UPDATE client_master_test SET member_id = 'test@test', mobileno = 'test@test', password = 'test@test';
```

Comment: I want to use courser which select one member_id from client_master then update it. i dont know about courser much more.